# Finding sub reporting employees in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
employee id reporting_head_id
----------------------------------
1           0
2           1
3           1
4           2
5           2   
6           3
7           4
8           5
9           6
```

Suppose I want all employees reporting under `emp_id=1`.

So I can get it from

```
select * from employee where reporting_head_id=1
```

It will return 2 and 3.

But I also want to **search employees** those who are reporting to `2` and `3` and so on. And employees reporting to 2 and 3, suppose to those reporting employees also some employees report so I also want their information and so on.

I want all the employees for the given `reporting_head_id` **plus** those employees who report to the `employees reporting` to the `given id`.

Now if I search for employees who report to `reporting_head_id 1`, `employees 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` should be **returned**.

Please can you provide me solution. I am new to `SQL`.

I have tried this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee 
WHERE reporting_head_id = 1 
   or reporting_head_id = any (select id from employee where reporting_head_id = 1)
```

so it returns 2,3,4,5,6

But how to find those who reports to 4, 5, 6 and so on

Comment: It can be done through a recursion function. But if you know the total no. of levels then it can be done through simple query too.

Comment: Please give us a format (output data) you want

Comment: hi i want upto 4 levels

Comment: If any of the below answers presented a solution to your question, please accept their answer by clicking on the check mark beside their answer. This will help future users searching for an answer to the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Other than a foreach loop which then querys for your addition results I'm not sure.

Try:

```
"SELECT * FROM employee WHERE reporting_head_id=1"
```

Then take the result and:

```
foreach($employees as $employee)
{
    "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE reporting_head_id=".$employee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but I believe this is an example of what you are looking for:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

Unfortunately, I don't think this is available in mySQL. However I found the two below questions that I think are similar and would give you a jumping off point:

[select ancestors using query like a recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215646/select-ancestors-using-query-like-a-recursive-function)

[Recursive MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647371/recursive-mysql-query)

Answer (score 0):

This will give some idea on the recursive function. We can make the code even simpler once we get the idea.

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE reporting_head_id=1";
$rec = mysql_query($qry);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rec)){
    $id = $row['empid'];
    $arr[] = $id;
    foreach(rec($id) as $key=>$val){
        $arr[] = $val;
        $arr[] = rec($val);
        rec($val); 
    }
}

function rec($id){
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM emp WHERE reporting_head_id=$id";
    $rec = mysql_query($qry);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rec)){
        $arec[] = $row['empid']; 
    }
    return $arec;

}
print_r($arr); //This array will contain the  reporting_head_id plus those employees who report to the employees reporting to the given id.
```